# multithreading in python not working as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

```
import threading
import time

def test1():
 print "hello"
 time.sleep(15)
 print "hello2" 

def test2():
 print "hi"

th1 =threading.Thread(test1())
th2 =threading.Thread(test2())

p=[th1,th2]
for i in p:
 i.start()

for i in p:
 i.join()
```

I am not sure if i am right, please correct me if I am not. I am expecting the output to be printed in this order hello hi and hello2. as i am expecting the two threads created to run parallely . but i am getting the below output, hello hello2 and hi.  Thread2 is running only after completion of thread1. Am i doing anything wrong? or my understanding or threading wrong?

Comment: You are calling the functions and passing their result(s) directly to ``Thread()``'s constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass a function reference to the `Thread()` class constructor which takes a "keyword argument" called `target` (*Default: `None`*).

Passing the result of a function call (*such as what you've done*) will have undesired behaviour especially since the first argument to `Thread()` is actually `group=None`.

**Example:** (*corrected*)

```
import threading
import time


def test1():
    print "hello"
    time.sleep(15)
    print "hello2"


def test2():
    print "hi"

th1 = threading.Thread(target=test1)
th2 = threading.Thread(target=test2)

p = [th1, th2]
for i in p:
    i.start()

for i in p:
    i.join()
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py
hello
hi
# 15s delay
hello2
```

See: [`threading.Thread()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread)

Specifically:

> `class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(),
>   kwargs={})`
>
> This constructor should always be called with keyword arguments.